# How to implement variance function in R

Tags: r, variance

I am trying to calculate the variance of a column from a data frame.I know that there are inbuilt functions var() for calculating the variance but I am not sure how to write a function for variance by passing my data frame column as variable.

```
var(banknote$Length)*((n-1)/n)
```

Comment: I don't think I understand- what's wrong with `var`? Is that giving you an error?

Comment: No I would like to solve it without using var function.

Comment: Do you want to include the correction or not?

Comment: I would like to implement the wiki variance and cross check whether R is giving me correct output or not..

Comment: No I am fine without correction..

Comment: Answer is below. Why don't you trust the result from R? Note that R gives the value *with the correction added.* The correction is useful because it makes the estimate unbiased.

Comment: @David The R variance gives for n-1 values.So I don't want to change my results with that little correction...

Comment: If you don't want the correction, you could just use the `var(banknote$Length)*((n-1)/n)` you have above. (I'm not sure why you don't want the `n-1` correction- if you don't use it, you're systematically slightly underestimating the variance- but it's up to you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the vector you're going to take the variance of is 1-dimensional, as in your case, you can simply do:

```
myvar = function(v) {
    m = mean(v)
    mean((m - v)^2)
}
```

This assumes (based on your example) that you *don't* want to use the `n/(n-1)` correction.